# webapp2 python regex in routing

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, http, webapp2

I'm trying to get webapp2 to handle urls in the form:

```
/case/e3627
```

where 'e3627' can be any alphanumeric string

Here is my routing arguments:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/case/<:^\w+$>', ViewCase)],
                              debug=True)
```

But I get a 404 error for my urls

I also tried `<:^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$>` for the regex but no luck

My app works fine for regular urls for example `/home` but not for the regex

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/case/(\w+)', ViewCase)],
                              debug=True)
```

should suffice.

Note that `^` means the beginning of the string, which clearly never occurs after `/case/`. I think that is why your regex did not work.

Comment: yes! This works, maybe I'm using outdated docs? http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Route